# Django - Send email with URL to newly uploaded file

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django app where users can upload PDF files. The PDF files will be saved on my cloud provider. After successfully submitting the PDF, I want to send an email to the user *with the URL to the PDF on my cloud*. I've been trying to do it by overriding `form_valid()` but at that point, the URL is not yet generated. The URL also isn't hardcoded, so I can't just point to a hard coded URL in `form_valid()`

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide us the code within `form_valid()` ? You need to insert your logic after super.form_valid() e.g.:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
   ret = super().form_valid(form)
   instance = form.instance
   # get the filename and send an email
   ...
   return ret
```